# How to add a default directory when importing user generated pictures in R markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I know that I can include an user generated picture in a .Rmd file using, for instance:

```
!["Title of my picture goes here"](path/to/my/image/picture001.png)
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically include the path, so I'd have to write only  `!["Title of my picture goes here"](picture001.png)`  and R Markdown would search for **picture001.png** in **path/to/my/image/**.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but it is my first post. My code lines just didn't appeared so I'm rewriting them here: I know that I can include an user generated picture in a .Rmd file using, for instance:

"!["Title of my picture goes here"](path/to/my/image/picture001.png)"

I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically include the path, so I'd have to write only "!["Title of my picture goes here"](picture001.png)" and R Markdown would search for picture001.png in path/to/my/image/.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting default directory as a global option in the r setup chunk:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='path/to/my/image/', echo = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: This will set the path for the R generated pictures. I'm trying to set the path for external pictures, i.e., pictures that are loaded from .jpg or .png files. I tried putting my image files in the fig.path directory but R Markdown is not able to find them.

Comment: Well, the solution proposed by jay.sf has worked after all. Sorry for the huge delay in updating this answer.